# Basic Java - Can one inner (nested?) class access another?

Tags: java, android, inner-classes

This is, what I think is a basic java question here:

This is for an Android project.  I have this setup:

```
 public class MyFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    ActionBar.TabListener {

     // lots of code edited out


    public static class RateFragment extends Fragment {

             // lots of code edited out

         class InsertTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void> {

               protected void onPostExecute(Void v) { {

                // I need to access ReviewTask here
                new ReviewTask().execute();

               } 

         }


    }

    public static class ReviewFragment extendsListFragment {

              class ReviewTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void> {

                  // code

              }


    }


}
```

I am really asking a basic Java question.  I know its not the best method in Android.

If you must know what I am doing: (If this is confusing, this information is low priority, just for some context) I call InsertTask when a button is pressed in RateFragment and inserts data into a MySQL database.  This is what I want to do in the above code:  In InsertTask, at the end, call ReviewTask in the other inner class.  This will update the listview (which is in the other tab).

Can ReviewTask be reached from InsertTask?

Comment: A class declared as `public static class` is not an `inner` class. `Inner` class are declared as `public class`. Perhaps you meant `nested`, which can be either `inner` or `static`.

Comment: Good to know.  I wasn't aware of that.  I'm an Android programmer trying to figure out Java.  Kinda backwards I know.

Comment: I may be seeing it wrong, but it looks like you have two inner `RateFragment` classes which won't compile in itself. But is possibly being masked by the other errors.

Comment: You were seeing correct. Thanks, caught the error.  I code it was named something else.  I corrected it up top now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can do it. I just tried it out. Here's what you can do though... have a method inside the fragment which the InsertTask's postExecute() method calls on. In this fragment method, you can create a new ReviewTask and fire the task. This way your inner classes just talks to your parent class which acts as a delegate between calls.

EDIT:

```
public class MyFragment extends FragmentActivity {

        private void delegateMethod(Object result) {
            TaskB b = new TaskB();
            b.doanotherthing(result);
        }

        class TaskA {
            ...
            public void onPostExecute() {
                Object result = new Object();
                delegateMethod(result);
            }
        }

        class TaskB {
            public void doanotherthing(Object o) {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: That sounds like a winner.  Dumb question:  How do you call this method?  this.myMethod() ?  EDIT:  Now that I think about it, how do you also call the class in the class from the method?

Comment: I've added some code sample (not exactly a runnable task...), is that sorta what you looking for?

Comment: This was the perfect way to access the other class and I got it to work.  I still don't know how to update the ListView in the other fragment, trying to work that one out.  It would be nice if I can just reload the entire ReviewFragment from within the RateFragment to refresh the ListView.  Either way, that wasn't the question and you answered what I asked so thanks!

Comment: General workflow I've been using for stuff like updating a listview in another class is... well you can do it 2 ways. 
1. Your parent class can hold variables to other fragments and you can call on their public methods from other classes.
2. Use the iOS way where you pass in a delegate which adheres to a java Interface.

I am still a bit uneasy about your fragments defined inside a parent class. Might be better to pull them out and make them function completely on their own, given the right parameters. Use interfaces or public methods to drive changes.

Answer (score 1):

If you change your declaration of RateFragment to be non-static, you can call

```
class InsertTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void> {

    protected void onPostExecute(Void v) { {

        MyFragmentActivity.this.(new RateFragment()).(new ReviewTask()).execute();

    } 

}
```

Because your InsertTask is still inside an instance of MyFragmentActivity, the keyword `this` is still usable, you just have to tell it which "`this`" using `MyFragmentActivity.this`. Note that this is the class name, not an instance name.

Comment: Eclipse says: no enclosing instance of the type MyFragmentActivity is accessible in scope.  But thanks for the try!

Comment: ahh that would be because RateFragment is static. If you remove that, this should work.

Comment: hey thanks for your help.  I actually used the other answer and got that to work...

Comment: Well then I'm glad you got your problem fixed.